# Google Places HTML/Javascript List

Tags: javascript, html, list, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

The below code works. 
-It shows "stores" on a map within 500 meters of predetermine location.
-It shows markers with store details on a map.
- It does show a list of places with the map, but only with the place name not details(I would like details).

If I want to output a HTML/Javascript list of the above instead of showing a map, how would find out how to do this?

Google Places API, focuses how to output onto a Map, but I don't want to output store information on just a map. If you have ANY clue, please let me know. I just need suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
var map, placesList;
var infowindow;
var service; //declare globally


function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(40.062664, -83.069101);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   placesList = document.getElementById('places');
 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
service.getDetails(request, callback);

}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: place.geometry.location
 });

var request = { placeId: place.place_id };
service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
   });
 });
 placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name  + '</li>';
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>
      #results {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -195px;
        height: 380px;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 5px;
        z-index: 5;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        background: #fff;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0;
      }
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 321px;
        width: 500px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      li {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 10px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      li:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
      }
      #more {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
     <div id="results">
      <h2>Results</h2>
      <ul id="places"></ul>
      <button id="more">More results</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're already filling an html list of places, why is it not enough?

Regarding place details, instead of trying to get the details of every retrieved place, I tried setting a listener on the associated marker. If someone ever clicks that marker, then I'll fire up the details request and open the infowindow accordingly

```
function createMarker(place) {

    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
    var request = { placeId: place.place_id };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
        console.log(details,status);
        infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
   });

  placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name  + '</li>';
}
```

doing it the other way around will cause an "OVER QUERY LIMIT" error, because you will be firing 500 simultaneous requests to getDetails.

**Update**: [here's a brief example](http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/afbd8e6f26638da01c62), using jQuery to detect clicks on the html list and firing a getDetails request.

Comment: No I want the details of the infowindow in placeList.innerHTML. I figured that placeList.innerhtml is out of scope. Also I believe I need to use placeList.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);  . I'm trying this out right now.

Comment: I would rather have the list load the name of the store with each marker, once the name is clicked on the list. Like I said I'm trying to get details of each store in the list as well.

Comment: so, when clicking on a list element, you want to append the place details to the list element?

Comment: Yes. I tried this with no luck: var request = { placeId: place.place_id };
service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
 
  google.maps.event.addListener(function() {
   placesList.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
  placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + details.name  + '</li>';
    infowindow.open(map, this);
   });
 });

}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Comment: Here's an older Screenshot example I used photoshop to come up with. However I'm sticking with the marker and not icons.http://s30.postimg.org/8v01cnu41/Screenshot_Figure1_2.jpg

Comment: See the updated answer. It's not very efficient, because I repeated part of the logic.

Comment: AH! THANK YOU! I actually saw an example using content as a variable, as you had it. AH I feel dumb! Thanks!